# Word for being ignored

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for ‘being ignored’.

> .... As people only feels love,care,respect,power,hate, insult, and [being ignored].

I can not find the appropriate word for ‘being ignored’.

Comment: How about the word disregarded?

Comment: Shunning means to avoid or ignore someone.

Answer (score 3):

As you have used *nouns* in your example.

`.... As people only feels love,care,respect,power,hate, insult, and [being ignored].`

I'll suggest you a noun.

## Desolation

(noun) [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/desolation?q=Desolation)

> **the state of feeling sad and alone**
>
> > "a feeling of utter desolation"

There is also a movie titled *The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***forlorn***

Defined by [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forlorn) as:

> Pitifully sad and abandoned or lonely.
>   *‘forlorn figures at bus stops’*

Comment: The only problem is that this is an adjective and not a noun, so it doesn't fit in OP's context.

Comment: @AleksandrH - Yes. agreed. However I *can* feel respect and I can feel forlorn. And I thought there were enough other problems with that sentence that some reword was necessary so it was worth suggesting.

Comment: @jim could you please share what other problems you have found on the context.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your example, I would offer "**loneliness**" or "**isolation**". They are akin to being ingnored in the sense of a shared feeling of *abandonment*.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lonliness

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/isolation